# VBA Excel runs well in debug, but fails to run in normal mode after Security update KB4022174

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code ran well till last night (18th of June, 2018).

But,
After security update, KB4022174 of Microsoft Excel 2016 - the VBA code fails to run in normal mode but runs well in debug mode. How to find and resolve this issue?

In installed Updates:
[image: Installed Updates]

The [Description of the security update for Excel 2016: June 12, 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022174/description-of-the-security-update-for-excel-2016-june-12-2018) says it has fixed **pasteSpecial** method which is used in my VB code. Is this the issue or something else?

Maybe the error occurs at `obj.PutInClipboard`

Comment: Create an error handler to catch where it goes wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with *fails to run*?

Comment: I added an error handler and I got the error: `DataObject: PutInClipboard OpenClipboard Failed`
Error Number: `-2147221040`

Comment: After closing and opening the xlsb file multiple times and running the code - it works sometimes, also fails sometimes. Which means the error still remains - unable to find it.

Comment: What about this: [microsoft community answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/dataobjectputinclipboard-openclipboard-failed-in/0639de5d-1cb4-4018-bbf3-df6dc06fc6d1)

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of users experiencing issue with Excel 2016 crashing when saving a file. It seems to occur only with file containing external links.

Uninstalling  KB4022174 seems to fix the issue. We are currently applying this workaround on other computers to confirm.

Comment: thanks! But the issue was resolved by opening the excel and changing a minor character in some worksheet then Saving it in another location. It worked. And also made sure that there is no other application opened which uses/watches clipboard.